# Does a table id is required in this case for appending data to it

Tags: jquery

I have got 2 tabs , on click of each tab , i am creating HTML and appending data to that particular table

This is my code

```
var myjsonresponse1 = [{
  "name": "JAYBARMARU111",
  "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}, {
  "name": "JUSTDIAL1111",
  "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}, {
  "name": "TITAN111",
  "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}];
var myjsonresponse2 = [{
  "name": "JAYBARMARU2222",
  "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}, {
  "name": "JUSTDIAL222",
  "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}, {
  "name": "TITAN222",
  "date_time": "2015-12-29"
}];
var tablesorterOptions = {
  theme: 'blue',
  widgets: ["zebra"]
};
$("#tabs").tabs({});
$(document).on("click", ".candlespattern", function() {
  var clicked = $(this).attr("id");
  var datatoselect = '';

  if (clicked === '#fragment-1') {
    datatoselect = myjsonresponse1;
  } else if (clicked === '#fragment-2') {
    datatoselect = myjsonresponse2;
  }
  var html = "";
  html += '';
  for (var e = 0; e < datatoselect.length; e++) {
    html += "<tr><td>" + datatoselect[e].name + "</td><td>" + datatoselect[e].date_time + "</td></tr>"
  }
  $("#candletable tbody").html(html);
  $("#candletable").trigger("update");
});
```

Could you please tell me do i need to create id's  also for each table to append data to it dynamically ??

1. By default tab1 is enables by default , how to disable it and show data only when clicked on the tab ??

http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/7618/

Comment: sorry forgot to put a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/7618/

Comment: each tab can have how many tables to be precise?

Comment: if you have multiple tables then you need  to assign an id  for each table to uniquely identify  each table and append data to them otherwise you can use any jquery selector

Comment: okay , but why tab1 is eanbled by default , how to make disbaled when initially page is loaded ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99p3yvv6/),

what i have done is, i made you `DIV.ui-tabs-panel` `hidden` as the document is getting ready,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.ui-tabs-panel').css('display','none'); 
})
```

the jquery library you are using is appending `display:none` to both of your `DIV.ui-tabs-panel` so we are simply overriding that.

now you need to fill data when you click on tabs, trick is when you click on `a.candlespattern`, i have added additional script for first making the 'DIV.ui-tabs-panel' visible and then i added the html to whichever `tbody` was visible, mind that the other table is hidden. the JS i added to `callback` of '.candlespattern' is here:

```
$($(this).attr('id')).css('display','block');
$("tbody:visible").html(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$(document).on("click", ".candlespattern", function() {
  var clicked = $(this).attr("id");
  var datatoselect = '';

  if (clicked === '#fragment-1') {
    datatoselect = myjsonresponse1;
  } else if (clicked === '#fragment-2') {
    datatoselect = myjsonresponse2;
  }
  var html = "";
  html += '';
  for (var e = 0; e < datatoselect.length; e++) {
    html += "<tr><td>" + datatoselect[e].name + "</td><td>" +   datatoselect[e].date_time + "</td></tr>"
  }
  $("#candletable tbody").html(html);
  $("#candletable").trigger("update");
});
```

to

```
var jsonResps = [myjsonresponse1, myjsonresponse2];
$('.candlespattern').each(function(i, t){
  $(t).onclick(function(){
    var jr = jsonResps[i];
    $('#candletable tbody').append('<tr><td>'+jr.name+'</td><td>'+jr.date_time+'</td></tr>');
    // not sure about that .trigger()
  });
});
```